# Azure Fluent API: how to login as myself

Tags: azure-management-api

Is there a way to log in to Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent as myself instead of as a service principal?

I want to use .NET instead of Powershell or the Azure UI to automate management tasks (via F# scripting), but I don't want to have to create a service principal that has my same permissions first. I just want to be able to use my own identity and permissions. SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory has various overloads for getting Azure credentials for a service principal, but I want something more like Powershell's "Login-AzureRmAccount" command that lets me log in as myself.

Is this a supported scenario?

Answer (score 0):

For .Net4.5.2 there is [FromUser method](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/src/ResourceManagement/ResourceManager/Authentication/AzureCredentialsFactory.cs#L27) that you can use
For .NetCore there is [FromDevice method](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/src/ResourceManagement/ResourceManager/Authentication/AzureCredentialsFactory.cs#L46) that can be used.

First one will let you use your username/pass. The second one will require you to follow the steps provided in the service response Message object (Opening a browser with the provided link and using provided PIN for authentication).